# error: prototype for 'void TNode::inititTree(TNode*)' does not match any in class 'TNode'

Tags: c++

I have an error with this code i try to just make it run what i'm doing wrong 
i get an error says :
Please guide me to correct answer

> error: prototype for 'void TNode::inititTree(TNode*)' does not match
>   any in class 'TNode'

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class TNode{
    private:
        int info;
        TNode *left;
        TNode *right;
        char ch;
    public:
        TNode* inititTree(TNode*);
        TNode*  addNode(TNode*, int val);

};

void TNode::inititTree(TNode *MyTree){
    MyTree = new TNode;    
    cin>> ch;
    MyTree->info = ch;
    MyTree->left = Null;
    MyTree->right= Null;
    cout>> MyTree->info;
}

void TNode::addNode(TNode *MyTree, int value){
    TNode TmpN = new TNode;
    TmpN->info = value;

    TNode *p = MyTree;
    TNode *c = MyTree;

    while (c!= Null)
    {
        if(TmpN->info < p->info){
            c = p->left;
            if (p->left != Null){
                p=p->left;
            }
        }
        else{
            c = p->right;
            if (p->right != Null){
                p=p->right;
            }
        }
    }

    if (TmpN->info < p->info ){
        p->left = TmpN;
    }else{
        p->right = TmpN;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    TNode *MyTree;
    MyTree->inititTree();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with C tag.

Answer (score -1):

It's exactly what it says: The signature of the definition does not match the declaration's. Your declaration is

```
TNode* inititTree(TNode*);
```

But your definition is

```
void TNode::inititTree(TNode *MyTree)
```

You declare your function returning a `TNode*`, but in your definition it's `void`. So either change the declaration to `void` or the definition to `TNode*` (and make the function return a `TNode*`).

Answer (score -1):

You've declared method `TNode* inititTree(TNode*)` in your class and defined a method `void TNode::inititTree(TNode *MyTree)` instead so it is a declaration mismatch. You should either change declaration to a void returning one or change definition so it returns `TNode*`